# List comments for picture with username cakePhp

Tags: cakephp

I have a problem with my comments.
 I have User model:

```
public $hasMany = array('Photo','Comment');
```

Comment model:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
            'User'=>array(
                'className'=>'User',
                'foreignKey'=>'user_id'
            ),
            'Photo'=>array(
                'className'=>'Photo',
                'foreignKey'=>'photo_id'
            )
        );
```

and Photo Model

```
    public $belongsTo = array(
    'User'=>array(
        'className'=>'User',
        'foreignKey'=>'user_id'
    )
);

public $hasMany = array(
    'Comment'=>array(
        'className'=>'Comment',
        'foreignKey'=>'photo_id'
    )
);
```

When I read data of a photo I got:

```
'Photo' => array -> info about photo which is ok for me
'User' => array -> info about user ok for me
'Comment' => array -> all comments but only with id of users.
```

How can I connet comments with users to get username related with comment while retrieving data about photo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `$this->recursive = 2` before you call find(), that will fetch all associations of every object returned by your query. Alternatively you  can set the `$recursive` variable inside any of your models.

The different types of recursion are as follows:

- -1 Cake fetches Photo data only, no joins.
- 0 Cake fetches Photo data and its domain
- 1 Cake fetches a Photo, its domain and its associated Comments
- 2 Cake fetches a Photo, its domain, its associated Comments, and the
  Comments’ associated Users

I also suggest considering [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) since you have complete control of all the data that is returned, down to specifying each field in any association

The photo model:

```
<?php
class Photo extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
}
```

And your find method will look like this:

```
<?php
$this->Photo->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'User',
        'Comment' => array(
            'User' = array(
                'fields' => array('username')
            ),
            'conditions' => array(
                'Comment.erased' => 0
            )
        ))
    'conditions' => array(
        'Photo.id' => $id
)));
```

Comment: It works, but also return all data connected with user: messages, friends etc. Is there posibility to get only recursive = 2 for comment table?

Comment: I edited my question with a link to Containable, I'll add an example so you can see how to utilize it.

Comment: Ok, now I can get data which I want but... when I type: $this->Photo->contain('User.name', 'Comment.content'); i only get username connected with photo, not with comment. Is there any posibility to get username (owner of the photo) and usernames conneted with comments?

Comment: One more question. Comment has column erased. How can i get only comments with erased = 0? In conditions I cannot add this.

Comment: Yhx a lot. Last question. I should keep this in model or in controller to keep MVC structure?

Comment: To comply with MVC patterns you would normally put this inside of a method in the Photo model such as getPhoto($id) or something similar and have the method return the find query. Then in your controller call something like $this->set('photodata', $this->Photo->getPhoto($id));. And in the view you could decipher the $photodata array

Comment: I post later one more question about Friends model maybe you will help me

Comment: Containable is good.  Recursive 2 should not be suggested ever imo.