# In Cakephp, if I find an object and it returns the "has many" items, how do I gather the objects that those "has many" items belong to?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, relationship

(look for a practical example below)

Hello all,

I'm attempting to turn this into one query:
Cakephp, being smart as it is, collects all the matching "has many" objects of the item I call a find on (in other words, all of the objects in a second table which use it's ID).  However these returned objects also have a second object that they are subject to a "has many" relationship from.  I would like to also gather the info of those objects.  Is it possible to do this in one query?

---

**Practical example:**

`House` --has many--> `People` <--has many-- `Employer`

House:
`id`, `address`

Person:
`name`, `age`, `house_id`, `employer_id`

Employer:
`id`, `name`, `location`

When I request the `house`, it returns all the `people` living in the `house`.  I would like to get each of `employers` for each `person`

Is that possible in one shot?

Comment: Have you tried using the [containable behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html)?

Comment: I have not... I can see how it restricts the automatic data, but how would I go about using it to go the other direction?

Right now, I'm getting House and it's related people, but I would like to also get the employer's of those people.  Now I understand how to use containable to restrict it to only the house data, or only the house and a specific type of person, but how would I use it to add the respective employers?

Comment: Containable is not used only for "restricting", but _containing_ related data. If you tell it to contain "People => Employer" (like some of the examples in the book), it should fetch it all. Maybe not in one SQL query though...

Comment: I'm afraid I just don't understand how it would be achieved.  Any hints?

Comment: @drHannibalLecter, from all that I can find, the examples are always recursive.. I can't find any examples where it recurses, then travels "backwards" to collect matching records.  I may completely be reading it wrong though, so any correction there would be much appreciated.  I don't doubt your right, I just can't seem to put together the appropriate query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code in your Person Model:

```
public $belongsTo = array('Employer' => array(
                                              'className' => 'Employer', 
                                              'foreignKey' => 'employer_id'
                                              )
                          );
```

Now try to request the house. It will return you the same data as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I actually discovered a slightly obvious, slightly ugly solution.  The downside is that it appears to be executing several unnecessary queries (such as collecting the `House` record for every single `Person`).  A better solution would be well appreciated.

Instead of using `House`, I used `Person`.

So if the query was `$this->House->findById($house_id)` it became `$this->Person->findAllByHouseId($house_id)`.  The results are not as nice of an array as with searching from `House`, but Cake collects all the relevant `Person` records, and also collects the `House` record and the relevant `Employer` records.

I hope this is useful to someone else.  I am still looking for a more elegant solution, but this certainly is functional.

Comment: Check out my answer to this question, it might help you see how containable can achieve exactly what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431267/list-comments-for-picture-with-username-cakephp/11431359#11431359

Comment: That's the answer right there, thank you so much!  If you want to post an answer, I'll give you the check mark.